# c++ vector of strings - issue with pointers

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write a method that gets a vector of strings and returns a pointer to a random element. Can you please tell what is the problem with the following code?

```
string* getRandomOption(vector<string> currOptions){
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    it=currOptions.begin(); 
    string* res;

    int nOptions = currOptions.size();

    if(nOptions != 1){
        int idx = rand() % (nOptions-1);

        while (idx!=0){
            it++;
            idx--;
        };

    };


    res = &(*it);
};
```

Thanks,
Li

Comment: As Guillaume correctly said, your problem is that you chose the wrong way to pass the vector to the function. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254) for how to pass objects to functions in C++.

Comment: What happens when curOptions is empty? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why return a pointer? Keep it simple!

```
std::string random_option(const std::vector<std::string>& options)
{
    return options[rand() % options.size()];
}
```

And since this works for any type, not only strings, I would prefer a generic solution:

```
template <typename T>
T random_element(const std::vector<T>& options)
{
    return options[rand() % options.size()];
}
```

Comment: +1 -- but see my answer for the same but with iterators. You could simply implement the vector version of this in terms of the iterator version.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: @sellibitze: Not really. OTOH it is the "right thing to do". @FredOverflow: What happens when `options.size()` is zero ;)

Comment: @Billy: How often do you have to randomly chose between zero options? :)

Comment: Never, but that doesn't mean the function should explode (or rather enter UB). (Throwing an exception would be okay...)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to "returns a pointer to a random element" you need to pass a reference to your vector. For now, **it is copied** !

You should do :

```
string* getRandomOption(vector<string> & currOptions)
```

By the way there is no `return` in your function for the moment, you need to add a return statement to send your pointer.

Comment: That should probably be a const reference seeing as currOptions is not modified.

Comment: +1 @Billy: The OP wanted a string* as result. So, you need a non-const ref. In my opinion this answer could explain a little the problem with respect to dangling pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the vector by value, i.e. the function has a local copy of the original vector.
Then you [intend to] return a pointer to an element in this vector. But when you return from the function, this local copy is destroyed, and your pointer is left dangling.

Comment: +1 You actually answered the question and explained the problem (unlike others)

Answer (score 4):

[Better version of the same](http://codepad.org/SDht6aoG), because it works with any container, rather than vectors only. Here's the C++03 version:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator random_element(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type
        size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size) //divide by zero errors are bad
        std::advance(begin, std::rand() % size);
    return begin;
}
```

If you're on C++11, you can replace the above with this:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator random_element(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
    auto size = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (size) //divide by zero errors are bad
        std::advance(begin, std::rand() % size);
    return begin;
}
```

Which gets around the `std::iterator_traits<t>::difference_type` glue.

Comment: +1as it demonstrates some good practice and was downvoted without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to change your function prototype to:

```
const string* getRandomOption(const vector<string>& currOptions)
```

or

```
string* getRandomOption(vector<string>& currOptions)
```

or else you just get an element from a temporarily copy.

Comment: You cannot get a pointer to a mutable string from an immutable vector of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the other problems mentioned in the other answers, when a vector resizes, any pointers or iterators (or references of any nature) become invalid. Don't return a pointer.

Comment: +1 because some prick downvoted all of us without commenting.